# Convert project to maven in Jdeveloper oracle

Tags: java, oracle, maven, jdeveloper

I converted my project to maven with this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ht8JgEAmrI8

My structure looks like this:
[image]

My pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>WebSocket</groupId>
  <artifactId>RMDXWebSocketEndpoint</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Generated POM from JDeveloper for project RMDXWebSocketEndpoint</description>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.oracle.adf.library</groupId>
      <artifactId>WebSocket</artifactId>
      <version>12.2.1-1-0</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}</directory>
        <includes>
          <include>*</include>
        </includes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <outputDirectory>classes/</outputDirectory>
  </build>
</project>
```

I can run Maven and Im getting a response that everything is fine 
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS

But In my code Jdeveloper doesnt see my libraries from maven. Jdeveloper behaves like that libraries doesnt exist

Maven Output:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building RMDXWebSocketEndpoint 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-container-grizzly:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-websocket-core:jar:1.3 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ RMDXWebSocketEndpoint ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ RMDXWebSocketEndpoint ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1252, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to C:\Users\tok\Desktop\RMDX_Middleware\java\websocket\RMDXWebSocketEndpoint\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ RMDXWebSocketEndpoint ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\tok\Desktop\RMDX_Middleware\java\websocket\RMDXWebSocketEndpoint\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ RMDXWebSocketEndpoint ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ RMDXWebSocketEndpoint ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ RMDXWebSocketEndpoint ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\tok\Desktop\RMDX_Middleware\java\websocket\RMDXWebSocketEndpoint\target\RMDXWebSocketEndpoint-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.043 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-12T16:25:28+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/217M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Process exited with exit code 0.
```

I have probably here a problem. Because it looking for imports here. How can I change that it uses Maven?

[image]

Comment: Could you please add Maven build output?

Comment: I added my maveb output. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: So if Maven build is successful then l think the issue is with JDeveloper not picking up dependencies to show correctly in UI

Comment: do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately no as I've never worked with JDeveloper

Comment: Check this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/maven11g-090173.html. Maybe it will help

Comment: In 12.2.1.2 you need to additionally add the jar files to the project properties libraries. Try 12.2.1.3 where the project picks the libraries from the maven directly and you don't need to manually add them.